# WKWebView Could not create a sandbox extension for '/'

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

I would like to use external file .html to use WKWebView. Or is there a solution without external file ? All is working good on simulator, but not on device...

Here is my code :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myHTML" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration =
[[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
[theConfiguration.userContentController
 addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"interOp"];
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame
                                 configuration:theConfiguration];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
```

I've read this topic : [WKWebView not loading local files under iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-working-in-ios-8-beta-4)

I don't want to use a server. I'm using Objective-C, and I want that it works on only one view, not like the https://github.com/shazron/WKWebViewFIleUrlTest project with 2 views and button and I need to have connexion with internet in the page (read iFrame).

What have I to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to copy all your web files to the app's NSTemporaryDirectory and call your index.html from there. Works fine on iOS 8.3 for me.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do this please?

Comment: @mark [Here is a good explanation about saving files to the `NSTemporaryDirectory`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12023082/3151675)